# Talking to remote docker from Linux to Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, chef-habitat

I've Windows 7 in which docker toolbox installed with VirtualBox running with default docker machine.

I've another Linux machine in which I've setup the habitat (habitat.sh) and trying to export the package using hab pkg export docker <..> command but it is obviously giving me below error at the end:

"Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?"

How do I connect to docker which is in my windows 7 machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to connect to remote using TLS. There is a way to do so using TLS as suggested in docker documentation.

Thanks